# Upload file image and text fields using ajax and Laravel

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel, file-upload

Is there any solution to upload **image** with some text fields using **Ajax** i tried a lots of solutions more than 5 hours without any good result. 
this is my code :

```
 var data = new FormData();   

 $.ajax({
    url: "upload.php",
    data: data,
    dataType: 'JSON',
    cache: false,
    //contentType: false,
    processData: false,
    method: 'POST',
    success: function(data){
        alert(data.success);
    }
});
```

HTML code :

```
<form action="{{ url('/compaign') }}" method="POST" id="xhr" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            @csrf
            <div class="card-body">
                <fieldset>
                    <legend class="font-weight-semibold"><i class="icon-cash3 mr-2"></i>Payment information</legend>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="xhr-block">
                            <label>Brand Name:</label>
                            <input type="text" name="compaign_brand" class="form-control" placeholder="Apple">
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="xhr-block">
                            <label>Content Type:</label>
                            <select name="compaign_content_type" data-placeholder="Select your content type" class="form-control form-control-select2" data-fouc>
                                <option value=""></option>
                                <option value="1">Article</option>
                                <option value="2">Web Application</option>
                                <option value="3">Mobile Application</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Content Image:</label>
                        <input type="file" name="image" class="form-control-uniform">
                    </div>

                </fieldset>
            </div>
            <div class="card-footer bg-transparent justify-content-between">
                <div class="text-right">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Enregistrer et Continuer <i class="icon-paperplane ml-2"></i></button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
```

What should id, because really i tried a lots of ways, i want to receive form fields and upload the image in the same time

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following:

`var form = $('form')[0]; 
var data = new FormData(form);`

Make sure these are false

`contentType: false, // requires jQuery 1.6+
 processData: false,`

Comment: The POST method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: GET, HEAD, PUT, PATCH, DELETE.

Comment: Are you selecting the correct form? Try `var form = $('#xhr')[0];`

Comment: check my answer please i have explained in my answer

Comment: If you are getting `POST method not supported`, it means your route for `action={{ url('/compaign') }}` is not set to `Route::post` in your `routes/web.php` or `routes/api.php` file, you should go to that file and see.

Comment: i have already : Route::resource('/compaign', 'CompaignController');